# Elasticsearch long and double mapping does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash for pushing logs to ES from DynamoDB:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        target => "doc"
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
            "[doc][dynamodb][keys][customerId][N]" => "integer"
            "[doc][dynamodb][newImage][callDate][N]" => "integer"
            "[doc][dynamodb][newImage][price][S]" => "float"
        }
    }
    date {
        match => [ "[doc][dynamodb][newImage][callDate][N]", "UNIX" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost"]
        codec => "json"
        index => "cdr-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "cdr"
        document_id => "%{[doc][dynamodb][keys][uniqueId][S]}"
        template_name => "cdr"
        template => "/opt/logstash/templates/logstash_dynamodb_template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
    stdout { } 
}
```

Actually mutate.convert does not make any changes, no matter if it is removed or added.

```
{
    "order": 0,
    "template": "cdr*",
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "cdr": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "doc": {
                    "properties": {
                        "dynamodb": {
                            "properties": {
                                "keys": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "customerId": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "N": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "uniqueId": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "S": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "newImage": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "callDate": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "N": {
                                                    "type": "date",
                                                    "format": "epoch_second"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "direction": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "S": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "disposition": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "S": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "price": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "S": {
                                                    "type": "double"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "uniqueId": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "S": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, doc.message contains all described fields, but they are not mapped. Here is the screenshot from ES:
[image: ES interface]
As you can see only string mappings work as it is supposed.

Error while querying says: `No mapping found for [doc.dynamodb.newImage.callDate.N] in order to sort on`

Does anyone know what is the reason of such behavior?

Tip: logstash debug `bin/logstash -f filters/logstash-dynamodb.conf --debug` does not contain any errors.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Are you deleting the index between changes to your logstash config file?  `mutate` won't change a mapping after the index is already created with the wrong mapping.

Comment: @Alcanzar, yes I delete all indices between attempts to reindex

Comment: Can you try to access fields as "doc.dynamodb.keys.customerId.N"?

Comment: @PavelK provide the full mapping for today's index: `GET cdr-2016.05.07/_mapping`.

Comment: Can you try to delete the template using `DELETE /_template/cdr` just to make sure it is actually redefined. I've seen cases that even with `template_overwrite: true` the template is not overwritten properly.

Comment: @PavelK Did you try my latest suggestion above?